# Fatal Error, Class not found

Tags: php

I have picked up this code from a tutorial and have edited it make it suitable for my needs.

```
<?php
//if we got something through $_POST
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    // here you would normally include some database connection
    include('config2.php');
    $db = new db();
    // never trust what user wrote! We must ALWAYS sanitize user input
    $word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
    // build your search query to the database
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM $tbl_name WHERE name LIKE '%" . $word . "%'";
    // get results
    $row = $db->select_list($sql);
    if(count($row)) {
        $end_result = '';
        foreach($row as $r) {
            $result         = $r['title'];
            // we will use this to bold the search word in result
            $bold           = '<span class="found">' . $word . '</span>';
            $end_result     .= '<li>' . str_ireplace($word, $bold, $result) . '</li>';
        }
        echo $end_result;
    } else {
        echo '<li>No results found</li>';
    }
}
?>
```

I am getting this error when I run the code:

```
Fatal error: Class 'db' not found in /home/peltdyou/public_html/do_search.php on line 6
```

I am very new to PHP so could anyone shed some light onto my problem..

UPDATE:

```
<?php   

    class db {

    function __construct()
    {
        global $dbh;
        if (!is_null($dbh)) return;
        $dbh = mysql_pconnect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
        mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
    }

    function select_list($query)
    {
        $q = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$q) return null;
        $ret = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($ret, $row);
        }
        mysql_free_result($q);
        return $ret;
    }   
 } 
?>
```

This is the db.php code.. I thought by replacing this with my own config2.php file I could get it to connect to my database.. Obviously not

Comment: Did you forget to include `db.php`? You're missing an include file that defines class `db`.

Comment: PHP is telling you that it can not find the db class. It could be found, this could be because it has not been autoloaded into your application, wrong path or it does not exist. How are you including the db Class . Do you have other code, which you can post?

Comment: Don't know what your config file contains, but you *can* include both separately (and probably should, as they're functionally different)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the sample script you used, and in it, they say:

```
// here you would normally include some database connection
include('db.php');
```

In the example, the db.php is not described, assuming that you have such a database file that you would use.  A little further searching, I found this [database class](http://scriptperfect.com/2009/09/php-database-class-the-right-way/), which they call "database.php", but you could easily use it for the code that you're trying work with.

Comment: Thank you! I found the db.php they referred to in the tutorial in the comments section. It had more relevant code which I didn't include. Now working perfectly! Thank you

Comment: Please don't propagate `msyql_*` function related code any longer. Also your answer is more a comment than an answer IMHO. Take care please.

Comment: Its not a comment at all - I explained the missing file and what it did, which was the cause of the problem that was being asked about.  Also, not all of us have the luxury of rewriting legacy code, so I will continue to answer others that are in such a situation because I want to *help* them - IMHO.

Comment: You should **not** just be loading up files like it's 1990.  Use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) (PHP) and follow PSR-4 http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4